# How to save upload image file to a folder on product edit page in backend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, image-upload, save

I have added a custom tab on admin product edit page. And in that custom tab added a image upload field. I need to save the image while saveing the product.

Is it possible to do it via ajax and a controller?

Please give me a solution to save image.

Comment: Have you tried anything for save?

Comment: i wrote a ajax to call a controller. But how to pass image details to that controller and on execute function what to write for the saving image

Comment: pleade share your code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using jquery, we can save the image to a folder.

In script, write this code

```
<script>
    function file_up(id)
    {
        var up_id = 'uploadfiles'+id;
        var upremv_id = 'upload'+id;
        var files = document.getElementById(up_id).files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            uploadFile(files[i],up_id,upremv_id);
        }
    }
    function uploadFile(file,up_id,upremv_id){
        var url = "<?php echo $baseurl ?>helloworld/index/upload";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                jQuery('#imgna'+up_id).val(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
                jQuery('#'+up_id).remove();
                jQuery('#'+upremv_id).remove();
                var img_va = '<img class="image" src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'custom/'?>'+xhr.responseText+'">';
                jQuery('#pre'+up_id).html(img_va);
            }
        };
        fd.append('uploaded_file', file);

</script>
```

Then, in your custom controller,

Class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $mediaPath  =   $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
    $media  =  $mediaPath.'custom/' ;

  //  exit;


    $file_name = rand().$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$media.$file_name))
    {
        echo $file_name;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File was not uploaded";
    }
}
```

}